# Istio tcp traffic mirroring

Tags: tcp, shadow, istio, mirror

I'm trying to mirror my TCP production traffic to our dev environment.
We're using istio and kubernetes.

I checked the istio documentation about mirroring:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: httpbin
spec:
  hosts:
    - httpbin
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: httpbin
        subset: v1
      weight: 100
    mirror:
      host: httpbin
      subset: v2
```

But this only seems to work for http traffic. Right?
When using for TCP I get:

```
unknown field "mirror" in v1alpha3.TCPRoute
```

Does anyone know an alternative way to duplicate the traffic?

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concept of TCP traffic mirroring in Istio. The reference documents what is supported for TCP:
https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/v1alpha3/virtual-service/

Comment: yeah I saw this.... Did hope that there is some kind of a different solution but maybe this will be just added in a later version.